# Why does not java cast int to double in expression automatically?

Tags: java, casting, int, double, expression

My problem:

```
int a = 30, b = 12, c = 2, d = 5, e = 1;

double result = (double) (a - b / (c * d) + e);

System.out.print("Result = " + (double) result + " - " + result);
```

Result:

```
Result = 30.0 - 30.0
```

What I want to see is: 29.8 !

I have integers but I want to evaluate an expression which I need to have in double precision.

Is there a simple way to do what I tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast one of the integers in your expression to `double`. Actually, you can't cast any of the integers. The important one to cast is one of the operands of the division, since integer division is the cause of the precision loss you experience).

For example :

```
double result = (a - (double)b / (c * d) + e);
```

or

```
double result = (a - b / (double)(c * d) + e);
```

This will ensure the division is done using floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

> why does not java cast int to double in expression automatically?

Because the expression where you're not getting a fractional value is evaluated based purely on the operands you give it, not the greater context (which would be *horribly* complicated). So `a - b`, `c * d`, and `... + e` all work with `int` values. Only once you have a final result do you cast it to `double`, and the compiler doesn't look at the greater context and guess that you wanted to do that earlier (which is a Good Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>).

If you want the operations to happen with `double` values, you have to tell the compiler that. In this case, you can put that cast in any of several places, which will then "bubble up" to any expressions the result is used in. Here's one place you can put it:

```
double result = (a - b / (double)(c * d) + e);
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/zNQRjI)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the operation between `int` is `int`. So the `12/10` is the int one `1`, if you want to get the double one `1.2`, you must cast one of the expression to `double`, like `double result = (a - (double)b / (c * d) + e);`.